# ¿Cómo realizar un scraping usando la id de un usuario de stackoverflow?

Tags: python, scraping, id

El objetivo del programa es realizar una wordcloud tomando como datos las etiquetas de un usuario de stackoverflow. Por ahora el programa funciona correctamente scrappea los datos de las etiquetas del usuario de stackoverflow y realiza el WordCloud, pero para ello es necesario poner directamente el link en el codigo para que funcione, y deberia hacerse a partir del ingreso de la ID del usuario de StackOverflow. En teoría creo que solo es hacer scrapping igualmente que con las etiquetas, pero aquí el problema es que el apartado de usuarios de stackoverflow esta paginado "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=week" y no se como hacer que al momento de realizar el scrapping se tome en cuenta todas las paginas que conforman los usuarios para llegar a identificar al usuario que se busca, e intentado varias cosas pero sigo sin dar con la solución, no se si estoy tomando los datos incorrectos para realizar el scrapping o si en si no lo estoy estructurando bien.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

#URL_del_perfil
url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano?tab=tags"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


#etiquetas_scraping
et = soup.find_all('a', class_='post-tag')
frec = soup.find_all('span', class_='item-multiplier-count')


#listas
etiquetas = list()
for i in et:
    etiquetas.append(i.text)

frecuencia = list()
for i in frec:
    frecuencia.append(int(i.text))

#unir_listas
frecuencias = dict(zip(etiquetas, frecuencia))

#Crear_wordcloud
custom_mask = np.array(Image.open("cloud.png"))
cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",mask=custom_mask).generate_from_frequencies(frecuencias)

cloud.to_file('wcloud.png')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation= "bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer, si lo único que quieres hacer es que se busque el Usuario y te lleve a la pagina de etiquetas puedes pedir la ID del usuario con un print y luego simplemente ir directamente a la pagina de etiquetas con esa ID.

Las siguientes líneas darían solución a tu problema:

```
#Ingreso de ID de usuario de StackOverflow por teclado
print("Introduzca la ID del usuario: ")
ID= input()

#URL_del_perfil
url = f'https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/{ID}?tab=tags'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Resto del código ....
```

Espero que te haya servido.